# Placing Firebase value event callbacks in a single place

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I often find myself writing this piece of code again and again in multiple activities when using firebase realtime db:

```java
        ValueEventListener v =new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dbSnapshot){
                String ourKey="";
                String ourValueID="";

                for (DataSnapshot childSnap : dbSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String childKey = childSnap.getKey();
                    if (childKey == null) {
                        //do some stuff 1 // and break/Continue/return
                    }

                    //or we can directly do something here, as we already assured  key is present


                    else  if(childKey.equals(ourKey)){
                        //do some stuff 2 // and break/Continue/return

                        MyClass myClass =childSnap.getValue(MyClass.class);
                        if(myClass==null){
                            //do some stuff 3 // and break/Continue/return
                        }
                        else if(myClass.getID().equals(ourValueID)){
                            //do some stuff 4 // and break/Continue/return

                        }
                        else {
                            //do some stuff 5 // and break/Continue/return

                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        //do some stuff 6 // and break/Continue/return
                    }

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                //do some stuff 7
            }
        };
```

although this is suppose to be how firebase works, it makes my code a lot more unreadable and difficult to debug. what could be a good approach to use these callbacks in a way, that i write this code once and de-clutter my code base?An example would be great.

Comment: Why do you say that this code is "unreadable"? What are your expectations?

Comment: @AlexMamo because when i have to replace the `//do some stuff x` comment with a function or some lines of code in each of my 10 activities, alongside other functions and callbacks each activity becomes huge. and difficult to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, i am using the following approach:

Suppose my firebase db consists of a list of objects which can be deserialised to the following format:

```java
 class MyClass{
        public String myClassUniqueID;
        ... other attributes;
    }
```

For the db i will be handling all value event listener's lifecycle in my own activity(i.e attaching to the db refernce via `dbRef.addValueEventListener(dbListener);` or `dbRef.removeEventListener(dbListener);`, But the process of creating this `dbListener` and passing it the neccessary tasks to be done would be managed in the following utility function :

```java
public interface DbListenerActions {
        void onMyClassObjFound(@NonNull MyClass matchedObj);

        default void onMyClassObjNOTFound() {

        }
    }



    public static ValueEventListener getMyClassObjectFinderListener(String id, DbListenerActions actions) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange:  our id:" + id);

        ValueEventListener dbListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dbSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot currChildSnap : dbSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String currChildKey = currChildSnap.getKey();
                    MyClass currChildValue = currChildSnap.getValue(MyClass.class);

                    if (currChildKey == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: currChildKey is null. continuing");
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (currChildValue == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: currChildValue is null.continuing");
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (currChildValue.myClassUniqueID.equals(id)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: currChildValue id matches our id ");
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: performing action and RETURNING(i.e  getting out of this callback)");
                        //do stuff here
                        actions.onMyClassObjFound(currChildValue);
                        return;

                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange:  current obj DOES NOT matches our id. continuing");
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: current object ID :" + currChildValue.myClassUniqueID);
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: --------------------------------------------------------------");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: user not found, performing not found action" );
                actions.onMyClassObjNOTFound();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        return dbListener;
    }
```

In this way, i am able to get the necessary log info that i want during my debugging and since there are only 2 possible actions that i want to perform, i get a lot more assurance on the working of my listener. 50 lines of necessary but redundant code from 11 activities combined to just 1 utility function!

Now all i need to write is this small , more easy to debug piece of code in each of my activity:

```java
  ValueEventListener dbListener=getMyClassObjectFinderListener("some_id", new DbListenerActions() {
            @Override
            public void onMyClassObjFound(@NonNull MyClass matchedObj) {
                //callSomeFunction()
                // callSomeOtherFunction(matchedObj)
                //...
            }
        });
```

Since i made the `onMyClassObjNOTFound(..)` function `default` i don't even need to provide that unless i really want to perform some action there. So this whole thing is working nicely for me :D

I asked on twitter about this thing too, somebody told me that an abstract class could also be used for such thing. I didn't  got to research more there, but if someone knows about that approach too, then let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onDataChange()`, you can just call a method:

```
ValueEventListener v =new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dbSnapshot){
                String ourKey="";
                String ourValueID="";
                retrieveDataFromFb(dbSnapshot);
```

---

```
public void retrieveDataFromFb(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
          for (DataSnapshot childSnap : dbSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String childKey = childSnap.getKey();
                    if (childKey == null) {
                        //do some stuff 1 // and break/Continue/return
                    }

                    else  if(childKey.equals(ourKey)){
                        MyClass myClass =childSnap.getValue(MyClass.class);
                    }
}
```

Comment: @anshsachdeva have you checked the answer? Basically you can create a method and in every onDataChange you can call that method

Comment: yeah i did but you see there are a lot of checks that needs to made on child key and child value , which would cause a lot of nesting. further more  there area  lot of calls to other functions in my "happy flow"  (i.e if i am able to extract out the whole `Myclass obj` from the `childSnap` , then i have to call another set of functions that are working with this `obj` ) I have come up with almost similar approach that saves a lot of my code lines that am about to write. Please do check and let me know if it would cause any error (:

Comment: This is the only way, if you don't want to do alot of checks then u must change the structure of ur database to prevent all these checks..

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to store all DB methods in a separate class so that you can reuse these methods which would make the **code look cleaner** and you are trying to get callback values when they get returned from firebase.

There can be many ways to handle callbacks for events what I recommend is to **use an interface** it will modularize  your code and make it look cleaner, so what you can do is to store the DB methods in a separate class (say FirebaseDB), create your methods there and use an interface to get the callbacks. An example on how you can do it:-

**Create an Interface either in the class or separate from the class**

```
public class FirebaseDB {

//This is your interface
public interface DBCallbacklistner {
    void onCallback(Map<String, Object> keyMap);
 }

public void getkeys(String any_value_you_need_to_pass, DBCallbacklistner dbCallbacklistner){
//I have used a different method here you can use your releveant method here
    database.somemethod(any_value_you_need_to_pass, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
       //Suppose you receive the callback here
            if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                Map<String, Object> keysMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) documentSnapshot.getData();
              //Pass the callback in your interface
                dbCallbacklistner.onCallback(keysMap);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Use that interface wherever you want**

Using the function from the class call that interface and use the values

```
mFirebaseDBObject.getkeys(value, new FirebaseDB.DBCallbacklistner() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(Map<String, Object> keyMap) {
            if (keyMap != null) {
                //Use your keymap here
            }
        }
    });
```

One more thing I want to point out is that If there are too many callbacks for different calls, I suggest to make separate interfaces based on logical seperation of callbacks.
Because if there are many callbacks in a single interface you would have to override each one of them, whether you require it or not.